# If a task is done by system itself, should it be a part of use case diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case

Quoted in Functional Specification is "System will generate online bill for FI Agencies on 2nd of every month and send it to respective agencies."

In this scenario, the system generates a bill on 2nd of every month. User can view the bill generated every month.

How should this be modeled in use case diagram, should i draw two use cases i.e, "generate bill" and "view bill" or only "view bill" because in "generate bill" no actor is involved and it is generated by system itself.

Comment: I advice to rename the question - you have really two questions in it. The first one, chosen for naming, is duplicate and the question could be closed. Set the name about necessity of differentiation of subcases.

Answer (score 1):

"System will generate online bill for FI Agencies" -

The bill generation is a case, and FI agency is an agent (a picture of a man).

As for separate "order bill", "generate bill" and "view bill" operations, they could be shown as cases at your will - due to specific reasons and size of the diagram.

The difference of behaviour  (every month or not), mentioned by you, can be shown on UC diagram as commentary only. This fact doesn't depend on whether you make different cases of them or not.

Later, in sequence, timing or state machine diagrams you can show this info as normal diagram elements, without comments. There you MUST show these operations separately.